# Wix: check for Oracle database

Tags: oracle, wix, wix3.7

How could I check existence of Oracle database on machine from WIX code? I want to create condition, which will check it before installation and will halt the installation if Oracle database was not installed. Something like that:

```
<Property Id="ORACLE_DB_INSTALLED">
    <!-- ? -->
</Property>
<Condition Message="Application requires Oracle database.">
    Installed OR ORACLE_DB_INSTALLED
</Condition>
```

I believe that it is possible via `RegistrySearch` or `FileSearch` elements (I actually don't know what to search). Maybe, any extensions exist for these purposes?

Thanks, any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every Oracle installation, there is an entry in the "Oracle inventory". By default, the Oracle inventory is located under "*C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory*". However, this location can be changed.

In the Registry, the location of the Oracle inventory is in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE", where you'll find the key "inst_loc".

Note that this key exists on every machine where an Oracle product (not only a database) is installed, so that might not be what you're looking for but it's a starting point...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @SimonKrenger, it was good starting point. Here is what I've found:

**1)** Parameter `inst_loc` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE` key contains path to inventory. And I've found such XML file: `inst_loc/ContentsXML/inventory.xml`, which, as I understand, lists all installed Oracle products. Useful section in this file is `HOME_LIST`. For example:

```
<HOME_LIST>
  <HOME NAME="KEY_OraDd11g_home1" LOC="..." />
  <HOME NAME="KEY_OraClient11g_home1" LOC="..." />
  ...
</HOME_LIST>
```

Each `HOME` entry contains Oracle home name and its location. So, you can check home name for containing specific substrings, i.e. `"Db11g"` or `"Client10g"` (but, maybe, it's bad idea, I don't know the rule for creating these names).

**2)** Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE` should contain subkeys, that have names with pattern: `KEY_{oracle_home_name}` (Like `KEY_OraDd11g_home1`). Such subkeys have `ORACLE_HOME` string parameter containing the product installation path. So, the installation folder can be checked for existence or containing some specific files.

For my needs I've created *WiX Custom Action* in C# to perform next steps:

- Check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE` for existence
- Try to find subkeys by pattern `KEY_*Db10g*` (I need 10g version to be installed)
- Get `ORACLE_HOME` parameter with installation path from found subkey
- Check installation path and several files for existence

---

Also, there was similar question here: [Detecting if an Oracle Database is Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304960/detecting-if-an-oracle-database-is-installed).